# Am I reaching memory limit

Tags: javascript, memory, jira, forge

I am trying to make multiple API calls and every call return array with 1000 elements, every element is kind of huge. I need to return ~ 7000 elements (100MB) with 7 API calls, but my code always stoped without any error on 4000 elements. Is it because I am reaching memory limit? How can I be sure ?

```
 export const getAllFindings = async (assets: [], status: string, assetType: string) => {

    let offset = 0;
    return await fetch({}, offset);

    async function fetch(all, start) {
        const newData = await getFindingByAssetIdAndAssetType(assets, status, assetType, offset.toString());
         all = {...all, ...newData['collection']};
        return (newData.page.currentPage < newData.page.totalPages) ? await fetch(all, offset += limit.FINDINGS) : all;
    }
}


/**
 * Get findings by asset id and asset type
 *
 * @param assets
 * @param status
 * @param assetType
 * @param offset
 */
export const getFindingByAssetIdAndAssetType = async (assets: [], status: string, assetType: string, offset: string) => {
    const ids = assets.map(({value}) => value);
    const apiKey = await storage.get("api_key");

    try {
        const response = await fetch(await baseURL() + sentinelAPI.FINDINGS +
            "?asset_type=" + assetType +
            "&status=" + status +
            "&asset.id=" + ids +
            "&fields=descAndSolution&limit=" + limit.FINDINGS +
            "&offset=" + offset,

            {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    key: apiKey
                },
                timeout: 10000
            });

        if (response.status === statusCode.SUCCESS) {
            await logger("Got all findings from Sentinel", logMessageType.INFO);
        } else {
            await logger("Could not get all SAST findings from Sentinel. Response: " + await response.json(), logMessageType.WARNING);
        }

        return response.json();

    } catch (err) {
        await logger("getSASTFindingByAssetId()" + err.message.toString(), logMessageType.ERROR);
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly does it stop? Does it crash or freeze? Or does nothing happen?

Comment: you have this `logger` ... what does it `log`?

Comment: @Geshode it just freeze. No error , nothing .